# How to convert pixel to translate value in d3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have a g element that I am trying to put on a top of my circle element by giving the cx and cy position of the circle to g element. However, this does not work because the g uses translate. Any idea how to convert pixel to translate?

```
colorPickerX = d3.select(dataPointId).attr("cx");
colorPickerY = d3.select(dataPointId).attr("cy");
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 300)
    .attr("height", 300)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate("+colorPickerX+","+colorPickerX+")"); \\This is wrong because Cx and Cy are Pixels
```

Comment: Just remove "px" from coloxPickerX and colorPickerY by using string functions. colorPickerX.replace("px","")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this using parseFloat:

```
//parseFloat will get the number and ignore the px in the end.
colorPickerX = parseFloat(d3.select(dataPointId).attr("cx"));
colorPickerY = parseFloat(d3.select(dataPointId).attr("cy"));
```

Then use it to translate the g group as you doing above.